# html dynamic change - how view changed contents?

Tags: html

Javascript run at page opening or later by user action like clicking a button with javascript attached, can alter the page contents and for instance change the layout in the browser.
Using right-click "View Source" shows the original content, not the changed one.
But how/from where can one retrieve the new, changed page contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see the live contents of the DOM, or you could use [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/)'s view generated source feature.